# accessing a member of a struct via pointer,results in error

Tags: c, pointers, error-handling, struct

This is a struct I have written.

```
typedef struct {
    int index=NULL;
    int sd;
    pthread_t tid;
    char* name;
}client_t;
```

Next I am making an array of these structs.

```
static client_t *clients[MAXCLIENTS];
```

Now in the main function, I am assigning values for these structs according to the position in the array.

```
    clients[freeslot]->index=freeslot;
    clients[freeslot]->sd=connfd;
    clients[freeslot]->tid=syscall(SYS_gettid);
    clients[freeslot]->name=threadnames[freeslot];
```

when i compile, i get these error messages.

```
code.c:185:12: error: ‘client_t’ has no member named ‘index’
code.c:186:19: error: ‘client_t’ has no member named ‘sd’
code.c:187:19: error: ‘client_t’ has no member named ‘tid’
code.c:188:19: error: ‘client_t’ has no member named ‘name’
```

I am confused about these error messages. Have I assigned values in a wrong way?

Comment: Are you sure you're including the correct definition of client_t, i.e. you don't have any more different definions lying around?

Comment: Remove the `=NULL` from `index`.  You should also consider whether you want an array of pointers (in which case you'll need to allocate memory) or whether you meant to declare an array of `client_t` instances - `static client_t clients[MAXCLIENTS];`

Comment: Removed the Null and the problem dissapeared. Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assignments are not allowed in a struct. Try assigning index to NULL outside the struct.